# Filter JsonNode Array in Jackson without Iterating

Tags: json, jackson, jsonnode

Json:

```
{  
   "type":"book",
   "children":[  
      {  
         "key":"123",
         "name":"book1"
      },
      {  
         "key":"456",
         "name":"book2"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I just want to get the name of the book as string when key = "456".

This is what I have:

```
JsonNode root = mapper.readTree(investigation.getFilterModel());
JsonNode children = root.path("children");
            if (children.isArray())
            {
                for (final JsonNode objNode : children)
                {
                    if ("456".equalsIgnoreCase(objNode.path("key").textValue()))
                    {
                        String bookName = objNode.path("name").textValue();
                    }
                }
            }
```

This works for me. I just want to know is there a cleaner way to do it without looping thru the entire children array? As the size of array can be big.

Comment: Selections and traversal of this kind are pretty simple when using JsonPath expressions. Have a look into [Jayway JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) lib or equivalents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That kind of query would not be possible with Jackson. You can at most use `JsonPointer` expression with it when you know the array index where the element is lying:

```
root.at("/children/1/name");
```

You can use JsonPath expression `$.children[?(@.key==456)].name` for your query which is supported in [Jayway JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#jayway-jsonpath) library.